# SQL Server - grant create table to schema owner

Tags: sql-server, database

Using SQL Server 2014 Express. I'm new to SQL Server (more familiar with Oracle). I have a schema defined and a user defined as the schema owner. I cannot seem to find a way to allow the user to create tables inside the schema without granting `db_owner` role.

This will not work for my DB because there will be multiple schemas. With this database level role, ie `db_owner`, the user (schema owner) can create tables in **any schema**.

My goal is to have a schema owner user able to log into the DB and create tables and manage the schema and ONLY their own schema.

Can someone help me with this? I'm quite frustrated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate? http://serverfault.com/questions/252808/with-sql-server-2008-can-you-grant-create-table-permission-within-a-schema

Comment: From the doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but the first, duplicate, doesn't work in 2014 and the ms doc reference doesn't have create table as a schema permission to assign.

Answer (score 5):

After much research, I was able to figure out the answer to my own question:

"Create table" is only a database level permission, cannot be assigned at the schema level.

A user can be defined as the schema owner.  If the user has "Create Table" permissions at the database level and is a schema owner, all tables will be created in the schema he/she owns.

A user cannot see other schemas unless granted "select" permission at the schema level by the schema owner (or someone with higher level authority). If the user has "Select" at the database level, he/she will see all schemas.